# How to ensure a variable containing special character won't cause further problems?

Tags: ansible, escaping

I can't figure out the proper way to  get Ansible `vars_prompt` to add double quotes around the password to ensure numbers and special characters are escaped. Below is an example of what I am talking about.

I have tried a number of combinations with no success. Basically when a password is entered I want Ansible to add double quotes around the password that helps ensure if the user has special characters it won't cause problems with Ansible or the ldap/database it connects to.

```yaml
vars_prompt:
  - name: my_password
    prompt: Enter password
```

```yaml
  --password="{{ my_password }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`quote` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) seems to be what you are looking for, as you seems to want to pass the provided password to a command flag.

---

Given the playbook, where I purposely added `private: no` to the variable prompt in order to see what the entered password is, but feel free to remove it:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
  - name: my_password
    prompt: Enter password
    private: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: --password={{ my_password | quote }}
```

This is an example run with the password `abc "' 123`:

```
Enter password: abc "' 123

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: --password='abc "'"'"' 123'
```